# facing an issue with mysql server

Tags: mysql

I was facing an issue while opening the mysql server in ubuntu 8.04 LTS.
the problem is as shown below:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql doesn't ask for root password when installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766900/mysql-doesnt-ask-for-root-password-when-installing)

Comment: Wait, did you say *8.04* which has been dead for **years**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [phpmyadmin doesn't connection with true data](https://askubuntu.com/q/1174132)